# qgis fails to create the legend when creating the colors of a map with the RGB data from the table

Tags: qgis

When creating a map style in QGIS 3.x from the attribute table, the RGB colors on the map are displayed correctly, but not in the legend - see screen shot. When exporting to a *.sld file, the wrong colors are exported.
[wrong color in the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxTPx.jpg)

table example

```
LEG_FARBCODE_R | LEG_FARBCODE_G | LEG_FARBCODE_B
  99       |        147     |      125
```

layer style code:

```
color_rgb(  "LEG_FARBCODE_R"  ,"LEG_FARBCODE_G" , "LEG_FARBCODE_B" )
```

the sld file looks like this (qgis automatically converts the rgb code to the hex code):

```
 <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>#729acf</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>#729acf</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>rgb_hex_hex</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>#729acf</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c84621</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
```

the colors of the features are calculated correctly, but the color of the legend is assigned randomly

```
<se:PolygonSymbolizer>
     <se:Fill>
        <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#729acf</se:SvgParameter>
     </se:Fill>
</se:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

so the wrong colours of the legend don't match with the map

there is no error, but the wrong color in the legend.
tested on Win10 / Ubuntu-18.4, / OSX and QGIS-3.6.x u. 3.8